# Logging in production mode with spring boot

Tags: java, angular, logging, spring-boot

I'm developing an application: frontend with Angular 2, backend with Spring Boot, 
and I'm using log4j to generate log files.

Locally, all works fine. When I deployed my application into a standalone Tomcat server on AWS, I cannot find my log files. Is there any further configuration to add to resolve this problem?

Comment: You should log to stdout, see e.g. https://12factor.net/logs

Comment: Have you configured log4j for tomcat (e.g. like [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j))?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Thank you for replying, I didn't any configuration of log4j in the tomcat server, i just added the configuartion file log4j.xml in the resources of my application.